# How to Hide my Forms when they are minimized?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Other than my main form, I need my forms to notify my main form and hide when I minimize them (instead of beeing minimized to the desktop window).

How can this be done?

My forms are created like this: [How to make my Forms always to be on top my main form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573762/how-to-make-my-forms-always-to-be-on-top-my-main-form)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handle the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message to detect the minimize:

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  ....
  protected 
    procedure WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;
  ....
  end;
....
procedure TMyForm.WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand);
begin
  if Message.CmdType and $FFF0 = SC_MINIMIZE then
    Hide
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

You can also notify the main form at this point by whatever mechanism you choose.

Comment: Why not call inherited in any case (like you did in your initial answer)?

Comment: Because that will minimise the form window before hiding it. May as well just hide it.